# How to make these strings print beside each other

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String A = "           AAA               \n"
                + "              A:::A              \n"
                + "             A:::::A             \n"
                + "            A:::::::A            \n"
                + "           A:::::::::A           \n"
                + "          A:::::A:::::A          \n"
                + "         A:::::A A:::::A         \n"
                + "        A:::::A   A:::::A        \n"
                + "       A:::::A     A:::::A       \n"
                + "      A:::::AAAAAAAAA:::::A      \n"
                + "     A:::::::::::::::::::::A     \n"
                + "    A:::::AAAAAAAAAAAAA:::::A    \n"
                + "   A:::::A             A:::::A   \n"
                + "  A:::::A               A:::::A  \n"
                + " A:::::A                 A:::::A \n"
                + "AAAAAAA                   AAAAAAA";
        
        String B = "\nBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  \n"
                + "B::::::::::::::::B  \n"
                + "B::::::BBBBBB:::::B \n"
                + "BB:::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::BBBBBB:::::B \n"
                + "  B:::::::::::::BB  \n"
                + "  B::::BBBBBB:::::B \n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "BB:::::BBBBBB::::::B\n"
                + "B:::::::::::::::::B \n"
                + "B::::::::::::::::B  \n"
                + "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB ";
        
        
        System.out.print(A);
        System.out.print(B);
    
    }
}
```

here's a simplified version of what im trying to do, when I run it A appears on top of B, I want A and B to print out beside each other but I have no clue how. very new to this, probably a stupid question but i cant find anything on the web so I'm hoping someone here can help me out

Comment: well you can't do that with newlines in them.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `\n` to determine each line and print it side by side:

```
final String[] aa = A.split("\n");
final String[] ba = B.split("\n");
IntStream.range(0, aa.length).forEach((int idx) -> System.out.printf("%s %s\n", aa[idx], ba[idx]));
```

Comment: May even be good to store those "fields" (yeah, they're just local params) as `String[]` and call `#split` on them right away, since I'd assume that would be their primary use. Nice appoach.

Answer (score 2):

If you split each character into lines, you can then iterate over the number of lines and print them "in parallel." A much simpler example follows.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String box1 = "+-+\n" +
                      "| |\n" +
                      "+-+";

        String box2 = "+-+\n" +
                      "|x|\n" +
                      "+-+";

        String[] lines1 = box1.split("\n");
        String[] lines2 = box2.split("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines1.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s\n", lines1[i], lines2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Information that i have to this case, i could suggest you a Souloution like this.

This is maybe not the prettiest soloution, but it is simple to understand, and it works.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String A = "              AAA               \n"
                + "              A:::A              \n"
                + "             A:::::A             \n"
                + "            A:::::::A            \n"
                + "           A:::::::::A           \n"
                + "          A:::::A:::::A          \n"
                + "         A:::::A A:::::A         \n"
                + "        A:::::A   A:::::A        \n"
                + "       A:::::A     A:::::A       \n"
                + "      A:::::AAAAAAAAA:::::A      \n"
                + "     A:::::::::::::::::::::A     \n"
                + "    A:::::AAAAAAAAAAAAA:::::A    \n"
                + "   A:::::A             A:::::A   \n"
                + "  A:::::A               A:::::A  \n"
                + " A:::::A                 A:::::A \n"
                + "AAAAAAA                   AAAAAAA";

        String B = "\nBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  \n"
                + "B::::::::::::::::B  \n"
                + "B::::::BBBBBB:::::B \n"
                + "BB:::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::BBBBBB:::::B \n"
                + "  B:::::::::::::BB  \n"
                + "  B::::BBBBBB:::::B \n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "  B::::B     B:::::B\n"
                + "BB:::::BBBBBB::::::B\n"
                + "B:::::::::::::::::B \n"
                + "B::::::::::::::::B  \n"
                + "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB ";
        
        List<String> arrayA = List.of(A.split("\n"));
        List<String> arrayB = List.of(B.split("\n"));

    
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(arrayA.get(i)+arrayB.get(i));
        }


    }
```

Comment: The first loop with `line = line.replaceAll` will have _zero_ effect on the contents of `arrayA`, since those changes are merely thrown away when the temporary `line` variable goes out of scope (a new loop iteration). The newlines are already stripped from `String#split`, which your answer incorrectly asserts otherwise.